# How can I get custom authentication flow data via REST API in keycloak?

Tags: rest, keycloak, authentication-flows

I made a custom step for the keycloak authentication flow. I want to get the JSON structure for it via REST API.

```
GET /admin/realms/{realm}/authentication/flows/{id}
```

and

```
GET /admin/realms/{realm}/authentication/flows/{flowAlias}/executions
```

return only build-in steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake! `{flowAlias}` should be a custom name for authentication flow.